# Vue Can read property

Tags: vue.js, axios

In my project i use axios and state management. I have store and separate files for models. In component then mounted i run

```
      this.$store.dispatch('getComputer2', this.$route.params.id);
```

and use v-model for binding. If i open page from another page press button

```
                 <router-link tag="button" :to="{ name: 'computerEdit', params: { id: row.item.id } }" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</router-link>
```

There are no errors. But if press F5 or open page direct link in console i see errors:
**[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null"**

In component i use computed property:

```
      computed: {
          computer: {
            get() {
                return this.$store.state.computer.computer;
            },
            set() {
                this.$store.dispatch("addComputer", this.computer);
            }
        }
```

What is the difference?

Additional code:

actions for receiving data

```
            const state = {
             computer: null
               };       

             getComputer2 ({commit}, id) {
    axios.get('/actives/GetComputer/' + id)
        .then(res => {
            let computer = res.data;
            console.log(computer)
            commit('SET_COMPUTER', computer);
        })
```

And this view:

```
            <b-form-group id="input-group-2" label="PC Name:" label-for="input-2">
            <b-form-input
                    id="input-2"
                    v-model="computer.name"
                    required
                    placeholder="Enter name"
            ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
```

Comment: can you provide more of the code. I don't believe the error you list is about any of the code you have in your question

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: the error is probably from this line: `v-model="computer.name"`. My guess is `computer` is null by default, instead you should make it `{name:null}` or something

Comment: Isn't computed property solve the problem? If i use <div v-if=computer, console without errors.

Comment: the computed property could be returning null, idk what your vuex store looks like. You could add a `v-if` but make sure its in the right spot